# How to use WebSocket with a Jetty emdedded custom server

Tags: java, xml, websocket, xmpp

I'm new to StackOverflow. I've searched about the topic, but I did not find anything really relevant.

Basically I need to develop a web 'Support Chat' system for our company. I know that there are a lot of available solutions out of there, but we need a custom solution in Java. We need to build a Support Chat web system where users that visit the web site can ask for support using the chat, and on the other side we have 'n' agents that take care of requests. We need to store each bit of conversation in our Cassandra cluster for Business Intelligence purpose. We need to develop the solution in Java (server side) and JavaScript+JQuery (client side).

**EDIT:**
After examining many XMPP based solutions (many are pretty old and no longer supported), probably I'll go with a XMPP-like custom protocol that covers only the features we need. To develop the solution WebSocket seems to be the most appropriate technology.

The question is, where to start ? I googled but nothings or less about how to use WebSocket with Jetty. Any link? Any resource?

Basically my thought is:

- A CHAT SERVER based on Jetty Embedded
- A small front end for the web applications (JQuery) that needs to talk to the server.
- Communication is based on WebSocket to avoid polling (the real problem)
- The XMPP-style protocol for XML over WebSocket. But this is not the problem.

The problem in how to use WebSocket with a Jetty emdedded custom server and web application.

**ADD**
As many have pointed out, WebSocket is not well supported for a general purpose usage. Instead AJAX is a more natural solution, but this implies the usage of polling. I've found some example on how to circumvent the problem with long polling, but I was unable to find a rock-solid implementation based on JQuery that was able to:

1. Use WebSocket when available
2. Otherwise, use JQuery-based long polling

I think that now the question is more clear. Sorry for my previous 'talk about' style question.

Comment: As you say you are new to SO, I suggest you reading the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close about how to pose good questions here. The question in this form is likely to be downvoted and closed as it cannot be answered exactly, only could be "talked about".

Comment: Sorry, as I'm new to the topic also, it's difficult for me to formulate a short and exact question. I can refine it based on feedbacks (if any), otherwise if it doesn't fit with SO policy, it can be closed.

Comment: @jabal: I've edited the question to be shorted and focused! Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 3):

I have used Atmosphere Framework (https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere). They provide several chat-related samples here: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/tree/master/samples

Comment: Wow, a lot of interesting stuff! Any online example to test without installing ? It seems to have all that one can require, any drawback of using this framework ?

Answer (score 2):

I would not suggest you to require Websocket for a support system, because there are plenty of people who use Internet Explorer which does not support it yet and likely will never support it on Windows versions previous to Windows 7: http://caniuse.com/websockets

You said you want to use "Java+JQuery" on the client-side. Are you sure you aren't confusing Java and JavaScript? These technologies have as much in common as [Iced Tea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iced_tea) and [Long Island Iced Tea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Island_iced_tea).

When you really want to use Java, you needn't use WebSockets, because Java applets can communicate with a server using normal TCP or UDP sockets.

When you mean JavaScript, I would recommend you to create a solution based on AJAX, because it's much more widely supported and you don't need the real-time performance of WebSockets for a chat application.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I mean Javascript, it was a my typo (fixed now). As in my second edit (see above), it seems that a mixed solution is the way to go: WebSockets(if supported)+AJAX(otherwise). But I'm looking for a rock-solid library.

Comment: socket.io could be the library you are searching for. It uses web sockets when available and has a lot of alternative fallback techniques like ajax, adobe flash and forever-iframess.

Comment: thanks, Socket.IO is the number one candidate. I'm also evaluating using it within Atmosphere Framework.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the [Fastpath plugins (Service and Webchat) for Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp).  This is an XMPP based solution that is intended to support your use case.  It is open source and Java based, so you can easily extend it to suit your purposes.

There is also support in [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp) for Java client based solutions (under the workgroup package).

Comment: Last update of the plug-in seems to be in 2009, I'm not inclined in using projects not actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

If XML usage is not a requirement, I would like to suggest [Bristleback Server](http://bristleback.pl). You can choose Jetty as the WebSocket protocol engine. Currently Bristleback uses JSON as messages format so this might be a limitation for you. Using Bristleback you can easily define recipients of the message, and everything is done without using low level WebSockets protocol components. Client side (using jQuery) library is also provided. On our website you can find some samples and tutorials (constantly expanding).

Full disclosure: I am one of the co-creators of Bristleback Server.

Comment: Interesting project. No XML is not mandatory, JSON is fine. It also possible to integrate it in a solution that support AJAX polling ? If no support for WebSocket.